# grep regex syntax

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following in a text file:

```
"ratings": [

            ]
```

I'm attempting to use grep -E to find all instances of the above in the text file.

here's my regex `"ratings": \[\n.*\n.*]` but when I run the command I get nothing back:

```
grep -E -B3 '\"ratings\": \[\n.*\n.*]' ~/Downloads/sample.txt
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any guidance as to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pcre grep.

```
grep  -oPz '"ratings": \[\n.*\n.*]' file
```

> -z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline

**OR**

```
$ pcregrep  -oM '"ratings": \[\n.*\n.*]' file
"ratings": [

            ]
```

**Update:**

To get three lines which exits before a match.

```
pcregrep  -oM '(?:.*\n){2}.*(?=\n.*?"ratings": \[\n.*\n.*])' file
```

Comment: Pz doesn't seem to be valid commands - tried using `pcregrep -B3 '"ratings": \[\n.*\n.*]' ~/Downloads/file.txt` still no luck

Comment: Thanks looking to get the three lines before the matching line as well hence the -B3, but `pcregrep  -oMB3` doesn't work nor does `pcregrep  -oM -B3`